# NameError: name 'urlopen' is not defined

Tags: python, import, nameerror

ok this is my last question so i finally found an api that prints good and that works but my problem is im getting errors if someone could look at this for me and tell me whats wrong that would be great

```
import urllib
import json

request = urlopen("http://api.exmaple.com/stuff?client_id=someid&client_secret=randomsecret")
response = request.read()
json = json.loads(response)
if json['success']:
     ob = json['response']['ob']
     print ("The current weather in Seattle is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF'])
else:
     print ("An error occurred: %s") % (json['error']['description'])
request.close()
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "thing.py", line 4, in <module>
request = urlopen("http://api.exmaple.com/stuff?client_id=someid&client_secret=randomsecret")
NameError: name 'urlopen' is not defined
```

Answer (score 25):

You did not import the name `urlopen`.

Since you are using python3, you'll need [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
req = urlopen(...)
```

or explicitly referring to the `request` module

```
import urllib.request
req = request.urlopen(...)
```

in python2 this would be

```
from urllib import urlopen
```

or use `urllib.urlopen`.

---

Note:
You are also overriding the name `json` which is not a good idea.

Comment: now getting this error  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/finaly.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name urlopen

Comment: i changed what you said but now get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/finaly.py", line 4, in <module>
    request  = urllib.urlopen("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/Urbandale,IA?client_id=QD2ToJ2o7MKAX47vrBcsC&client_secret=0968kxX4DWybMkA9GksQREwBlBlC4njZw9jQNqdO")
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined  sorry for the hasle but im toatly new to this learning to code on my pi that i got a week ago

Comment: Dont use urllib.urlopen. use urlopen, or request.urlopen.

Comment: ok i got it changed but now incountering an error in python 3 when i run it i had to cahnge response = request.read() to response = request.read().decode("utf-8") but now geting this error type error unsuported operand tyoe(s) for %: 'nonetype and 'tuple' please help total noob here

Comment: If we're fixing the other issues, since the OP is using Python 3, `print` is a function, so `print("whatever") % stuff` won't work because `print` returns `None`..

Comment: @DSM Right. But That should a comment for the original post (otherwise  the OP won't see it).

Answer (score 2):

Python does not know that the `urlopen` you refer to (line 4) is the `urlopen` from `urllib`. You have two options:

1. Tell Python that it is - replace `urlopen` with `urllib.urlopen`
2. Tell Python that ALL references to `urlopen` are the one from `urllib`: replace the line `import urllib` to `from urllib import urlopen`

Comment: getting this error with the first one Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/finally2.py", line 4, in <module>
    request  = urllib.urlopen("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/Urbandale,IA?client_id=QD2ToJ2o7MKAX47vrBcsC&client_secret=0968kxX4DWybMkA9GksQREwBlBlC4njZw9jQNqdO")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' and for the second one i get thisTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/finally2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name urlopen

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
import urllib
import json

request  = urllib.urlopen("http://api.example.com/endpoint?client_id=id&client_secret=secret")
response = request.read()
json = json.loads(response)

if json['success']:
     ob = json['response']['ob']
     print ("The current weather in Seattle is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF'])

else:
     print ("An error occurred: %s") % (json['error']['description'])

request.close()
```

You didn't specifically import the `urlopen()` method from the `urllib` library.

Comment: i get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/finally2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name urlopen

Comment: that's not from my suggestion.. try running exactly what is written above; I've tested it and it works.

Comment: r u running python 2 or 3 im running 3

Comment: I'm on 2.7 .. as another answer has said, you should be using `import urllib.request` for python 3.  That should get it working for you.